# getView in BaseAdapter calling behaviour on fling

Tags: android, android-listview

Say I have a listview of 20 elements displaying 8 elements at a time to the screen.

I have noticed that getView is called many more times when I perform a fling operation on the listview than when I scroll the list normally (In both cases scrolling/flinging from top to bottom). The question is **Why does flinging call getView more times than normal scrolling?**

I understand that there are ways to make getView efficient however I would like to understand why getView is called more often for a fling operation.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of the `getView()` method is such that it will be called as many times as the views will be changed in the screen. So whenever you do the scrolling of your ListView it will recycle the old records and will inflate the new records by calling the `getView()` method. So your view will be recreated each and everytime you scroll the List and will show the new records when scrolling stops.

The adapters are built to reuse Views, when a View is scrolled so that is no longer visible, it can be used for one of the new Views appearing. This reused View is the convertView. If this is null it means that there is no recycled View and we have to create a new one, otherwise we should use it to avoid creating a new.

`convertView` is for recycling. Let's say you have a listview which can only display 10 item at a time, and currently it is displaying item 1 -> item 10. When you scroll down one item, the item 1 will be out of screen, and item 11 will be displayed. To generate View for item 11, the `getView()` method will be call, and `convertView` here is the view of item 1 (which is not neccessary anymore).

So whenever you do the fling at that time your scrolling gets more faster so your adapter will be calling the `getView()` method as much fast as many records will comes into the screen. Thats why its showing the different number of counts of `getView()` method.

So instead create a new `View` object for item 11 (which is costly), why not re-use `convertView`? 
we just check `convertView` is null or not, if null create new view, else re-use `convertView`.

Comment: I am already re-using the convertView and also use a holder, but that is not the issue. You said "adapter will be calling the getView() method as much fast as many records will comes into the screen", but when I scroll slowly and when I fling I go through the same number of views, however the getView gets called different number of times.

Comment: whenever you do the fling at that time your scrolling gets more faster so your adapter will be calling the getView() method as much fast as many records will comes into the screen. Thats why its showing the different number of counts of getView() method.

Comment: Yes, but when I scroll slowly I get the same number of records into screen, because in both cases I am scrolling all the way to the bottom.

Comment: Yes it will give that many number of records as many will be visible only.

Comment: That is what should happen, however it doesn't. Add a log at the beginning of a getView to see when it's called, then do a fling and a normal scroll and compare the results. You will see they are different, even though you displayed in both cases the same number of records.